# How can I add some route prefix to all controllers in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using annotations to define routes in controllers and I have 15 controllers. All are executed by `/path1` , `/path2`.

Is there any way that in all those controller , I can access them via `/admin/path1` and `/admin/path2`?

I don't want to enter that by changing each file.

Can I do that from a single location? I mean the whole bundle should open via `/admin` and then their respective paths.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

```
# app/config/routing.yml
acme_hello:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin
```

or if using annotations

```
resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this in `routing.yml`:

```
Admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /admin
```

Answer (score 4):

Just define the annotation for your Class (not for method)

```
/**
* @Route("/blog")
*/
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix

Comment: The author asked for a global way.

Comment: This method works for me since I wanted it to be on a certain controller not the whole bundle.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prefix specific controller DevController for example and have something like:

myproject.com/dev/test

in your Controller add the following Route annotation as in example:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/dev")
 */
class DevController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function testSavingAction(){

        return new Response();
    }
....
```