# Rewrite request_uri for symfony2 routing

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite all address on my website to something like this :

```
http://domain.com/toto/myPage
http://domain.com/myPage
```

The problem is that when I modify my .htaccess to automatically add a prefix in all path, symfony (2) don't handle it and all routes end up to a 404 ...

How can I edit my .htaccess to modify the REQUEST_URI ?
This don't work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php/toto [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to _add_ such prefix to all your routes? [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644169/how-can-i-add-some-route-prefix-to-all-controllers-in-symfony2) then. If you want to _remove_ it, do it manually without messing w/ `.htaccess`.

Comment: Please provide more information. What are your current routes? Can you add 'toto/' to it (as a prefix)?

Comment: The fact is that we want to route some part of the app in a domain, and other in another domain. So we don't want to touch the sources but just the .htaccess to emulate a prefix (wich will allow to access only one part of the app at a time).

Comment: For exemple, we want to share code between www.toto.com and www.yaya.com :
ou dev version routes are :
test.dev/toto => www.toto.com
test.dev/yaya => www.yaya.com
How can we prefix all request URI properly ?

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround (so the question is still valid).

But for industrialisation, we create a file

```
app/config/routing.yml.dist
```

containing all main bundle route declaration, and we removed the routing.yml from build.
So we just have to copy the sources for each domain, and edit the routing.yml file to remove ou change the prefix on the needed bundles.
This way we can continue to share the database.

But I'm still curious to how to do it with a .htaccess file.