# Error with htaccess when Symfony deployed in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I would like my Symfony application to be reachable at URL `http://www.mydomain/site/`, so I deployed the Symfony files in this way:

```
web_root
|
|--- site
|   |
|   |--- app
|   |--- src
|   |--- config
|   |--- web
|   |--- (other files)
|
|--- .htaccess
```

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/site/web/
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) /site/web/$1
```

Unluckily, with this configuration whenever I try to reach `http://www.mydomain/site` I get a 404 error with message: `no route found for "GET /site/" [...]`.

However, if I change the `RewriteRule` to the following one or if I visit `http://www.mydomain/site/web/`, everything works fine (except that my URL changes):

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) /site/web/$1 [R]
```

How should I configure my .htaccess to make the site work?

Also, shouldn't the `/site/` prefix be removed by the rewrite rule, in order to pass to `app.php` only the relevant route?

Comment: It seems, that the rule works and the app.php front controller is called. Maybe you need to prefix the routes with /site, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11644169/1741542, especially the first two answers.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes, by adding the prefix both to the route and to the assets everything works correctly. However, why does my controller see the `/site/whatever` path instead of `/whatever`? The rewrite rule should remove the `/site` prefix so that the controller sees only `/whatever`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't dig deep enough into the sources, maybe Symfony looks into REQUEST_URI, which doesn't change with a rewrite only with a redirect.

Comment: I think you are right, that would explain the experienced behavior. Thanks for the info ;)